# How to make DevExpress report viewer toolbar responsive in angular

Tags: angular, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress report viewer in an angular project. The issue is toolbar is not adaptive for mobile view, so some icons from the right side are hidden depending on the screen width

```
<dx-report-viewer [reportUrl]="reportUrl" height="800px">
    <dxrv-request-options [invokeAction]="invokeAction" [host]="hostUrl"></dxrv-request-options>

    <dxrv-callbacks (CustomizeLocalization)="CustomizeLocalization($event)"
                    (BeforeRender)="beforeRender($event)">
    </dxrv-callbacks>
</dx-report-viewer>
```

[image]